# C++ How to send and read an array through a pipe?

Tags: c++, arrays, pipe

I have a program which forks and I want the parent and the child process to communicate through an array of size 3, but I am not able to do this. Reading from the pipe meant to pass the array to the child process seems to always give the wrong value or does not work.
Here is the code I use:

```
int main()
{

   int pw[2];
   int piped = pipe(pw[2]);

   pid_t pid = fork();


   if(pid == 0)
   {
     close(pw[0]);
     int d1[3] = {1, 2, 3};
     write(pw[1], d1, 3*sizeof(int));
   }
   else
   {
     close(pw[1]);
     int d2[3] = {0, 0, 0};
     read(pw[0], d2, 3*sizeof(int));
     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     {
        cout << d2[i];
     }
   }
 }
```

Most of the time I don't even get anything printed to the screen. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is why "Yoda style" comparisons (`if (0 == pid)`) were invented--if you leave out an `=` so it turns into an assignment, it won't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookint at [man 2 pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe),

```
int piped = pipe(pw[2]);
```

should be

```
int piped = pipe(pw);
```

**(Obsolete due to OP's update) :**

> ```
> if(pid = 0)
> ```
>
> should be
>
> ```
> if(pid == 0)
> ```

Comment: Take a look at my modification.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (pid = 0)
```

Always is false, and changes `pid` to be zero.